# Move Feature not showing on edit bar

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I am using QGis 3.2 and on the edit bar I don't have the move feature icon available (even before loading the file). I have seen situation where it is blocked but without showing completely on the bar is a novelty to me. Can anyone give me a hand?

[image: Edit bar without move feature available (or even blocked)]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think `Move Feature(s)` icon has moved to `Advanced Digitizing Toolbar`.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Like the previous reply said, you need to turn the Advanced Digitizing Toolbar on. You can find that by going to View -> Toolbars --> Advanced Digitizing Toolbar.

[image]